# AWS DynamoDB does not save empty string set properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We are using DynamoDB for data storage with the .NET API and one of our object types has a non-key property that is a `HashSet<string>` type.  Something like this:

```
public class LicenseRule
{
   ...
   public HashSet<string> LicenseIds { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

When we save this with an object that has that property as an empty set it works just fine; the property is not present in DynamoDB and comes back as an empty set when we retrieve it, so far so good.  However, if we save an object that has a non-empty set (i.e. it contains `["123","456"]`) that also works, but then if update it by emptying the set and then saving the object again, it doesn't remove the value.  Saving works fine (no errors or exceptions) but then if you ping DynamoDB again for that object it comes back with the property populated how it was before.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not support empty set types, and the likely cause to your issue:

> Each value within a set must be unique. The order of the values within a set is not preserved. Therefore, your applications must not rely on any particular order of elements within the set. DynamoDB does not support empty sets, however, empty string and binary values are allowed within a set.

[Src](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html)

Comment: Right, but with the .NET SDK it will update to remove the property on the object if it's an empty set.  That's why it doesn't throw an error when you save the initial object with an empty set.  It just doesn't update the object to remove the property if you save a new version with an empty set.